# Map my second hard drive to be SDA1

Tags: mount, hard-drive, banshee

I recently switched hard drive and had a fresh install (13.10). I copied across the settings from some programs, including banshee and Transmission.

On the old install, my primary HDD was SDA and the storage partition mounted at SDA2.

This partition now mounts at /media/pc-user/0391a5db-61d8-4c3d-b633-59c710ed4386 and is called SDC1.

The new HDD is SDA and sda2 is an "extended partition". Can I format it and put a link there?

This image shows what's currently sda2 and what I need to get to.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEqHM.jpg

How can I get it to mount at /media/pc-user/SDA2 so that banshee and transmission automatically find their files?

Answer (score 2):

You can enter the mount in /etc/fstab so it gets automatically mounted with the options you prefer.

The line in fstab should like like:

> UUID=0391a5db-61d8-4c3d-b633-59c710ed4386 /media/pc-user/SDA2 auto
>   defaults 0 0

Now you have to make a directory in /media/pc-user named SDA2:

> sudo mkdir /media/pc-user/SDA2

After reboot the dir will be linked to your partition (SDC1)

No need to reformat your hdd, the dir /media/pc-user/SDA2 is just a name and does not do anything with you actual SDA2 partition.

Comment: Hi thanks, I had tried that and it turns out it wasn't working because sda2 is occupied. Please see my edit - can I reformat the extended partition to EXT4 and put a link there to the storage partition?

Comment: I do not think there is a reason to reformat but the directory should exist when trying to mount a partition to it.

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: The UUID part is the partition you want to access, then follows the name of the directory to which it should be linked, then filesystem type and options.
So /media/pc-user/SDA2 is just the name of a directory, nothing more. After mounting it will be linked to partition UUID which is SDC1. Instead of SDA2 you can use any name you want, the only rule is that the directory should exist before it can be linked to a partition. That is done in the instruction by using sudo mkdir.